# How do we extend the javafx property class properly?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I am trying to extend the SimpleDoubleProperty and override the set method to make the listener code run even when the new value and old value are equal. But when I run the code it's not firing the listener code. What's wrong here ? I am having a hard time figuring out this :\

**SimpleDouble.java**

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;

public class SimpleDouble extends SimpleDoubleProperty {

    public SimpleDouble() {

    }

    public SimpleDouble(double arg0) {
        super(arg0);

    }

    public SimpleDouble(Object arg0, String arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);

    }

    public SimpleDouble(Object arg0, String arg1, double arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);

    }

    @Override
    public void set(double arg0) {
           if (isBound()) {
                throw new java.lang.RuntimeException("A bound value cannot be set.");
           }
           fireValueChangedEvent();
    }

}
```

**Bill.java**

```
class Bill {


    private DoubleProperty amountDue = new SimpleDouble();


    public final double getAmountDue(){return amountDue.get();}


    public final void setAmountDue(double value){amountDue.set(value);}


    public DoubleProperty amountDueProperty() {return amountDue;}

}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Bill electricBill = new Bill();

       electricBill.amountDueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener(){
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue o,Object oldVal, 
                 Object newVal){
             System.out.println("Electric bill has changed!");
        }
      });

      electricBill.setAmountDue(100.00);
      electricBill.setAmountDue(100.00);



    }
}
```

Comment: Your `set()` method doesn't appear to actually change the value...

Comment: Anyway, if you dig through the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9/rt/file/c734b008e3e8/modules/javafx.base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/binding/ExpressionHelper.java) (see `SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent()`), the implementation of `fireValueChangedEvent()` does actually check (again) that the new value is different to the old value. The real problem is that you're trying to use inheritance to change the actual functionality of the "change" event, not merely its implementation. The API is designed so that change events are fired when the value *changes*.

Comment: That explains. Thanks. But is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Do what, though? You're trying to change the actual *semantics* of a property. A property represents a value. A change listener is called if the value *changes*. Calling `set(...)` with the existing value doesn't change the value. You can't change the semantics of existing classes. Whatever it is you're trying to do needs to be solved at a level different to the property itself.

Comment: Instead of trying to change the fundamental behavior of DoubleProperty, consider adding a second property that you can update reliably, like `ObjectProperty<Instant>`.  Listen to that property and when it changes, re-read the DoubleProperty.